# WordPress URL alias - how to access a single thanks page from multiple URLs

Tags: wordpress, url, routes

Without using .htaccess, how can I have multiple URLs for a single WordPress page?

Here's why I want to do this:

I have a single thanks page that I want to use for multiple items. I want the thanks page for each item to have its own unique URL so I can create a goal in Google Analytics for each item's thanks page, e.g.

```
mysite.com/item-1/thanks
mysite.com/item-2/thanks
mysite.com/item-3/thanks
```

I don't really want to have to create 3 separate (but identical) thanks pages.

PHP frameworks have routing options that would make this easy, but I can't find a way to do it with WordPress!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213016/access-the-same-page-from-multiple-urls-wildcard

Add this to functions.php:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
  $page_id = 123; //The id of the page you want to serve
  add_rewrite_rule('^some-item-url/thanks', 'index.php?page_id=' . $page_id, 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
```

Then flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WP Admin go to  Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.